# How do I retrieve the content of a OneNote page using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm swapping out my usage of the old OneDrive SDK to programmatically access the contents of OneNote in a UWP app, and I've begun using the Microsoft Graph for .NET SDK. One of the things I need to do is get a specific page's content. Currently, I'm attempting to do so like this:

```
await _graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages
    .Request()
    .Filter("tolower(title) eq 'shopping list'")                    
    .GetAsync();
```

...which works, and gets me all the pages in my notebook with the title of "shopping list". However, all of those pages have a `null` `Content` property, leaving me unable to get the HTML content of those pages. I can verify that at least one of these pages does, in fact, have content in the OneNote application.

I've read through the documentation for the SDK, and it appears that I should just be getting a `Stream` back without any further action. Is there a step I'm missing, or am I using the API incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the SDK supports getting an individual page's Content directly, but the syntax to do so isn't very discoverable. It is:

```
Stream pageContent = await _graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages[page.Id]
    .Content // This could be omitted to retrieve every property on the page, presumably
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Turns out an `IOnenotePagesCollectionRequestBuilder` returned by `_graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages` supports key-style indexing to retrieve a specific page. Totally unfindable with the default intellisense dropdown =/

Answer (score 1):

Page content could be requested per single page, for example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{page-id}/content
```

Per collection of pages content could be requested like this (via `contentUrl` property of [`Page` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/page?view=graph-rest-1.0)):

```
var result = await graphClient.Me.Onenote.Pages.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (var page in result)
{

     //download Page content
     var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, page.ContentUrl);
     await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
     var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
     var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  //get content as HTML 

}
```

Comment: Upvote because this works, but it turns out there's a (very!) poorly-documented solution that uses the SDK and doesn't require falling back to sending an HTTP request by almost-hand.